# Proving that the spectral radius of a normal operator equals to its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I need to prove that if $A$ is a normal operator, then the spectral radius of $A$ is $||A||$.

I know that for any linear operator $T:H_1 \rightarrow H_2$, we have that

$||T^*T|| = ||T||^2$

Therefore, we can write

$||{A^2}^n||$$^2$ = $||{{A^*}^2}^n{A^2}^n||$ = $||{(A^*A)^2}^n||$( As $A$ is a normal operator)

Now I let $B= A^*A$.

Then, clearly $B$ is a self-adjoint.

Now I am trying to show that $||{B^2}^n||^\frac{1}{2^n}$ = $||B||$.

I am trying to prove the above by induction.

I can see that for $n = 1$ it will be true as $B$ is a normal operator therefore $||B^2|| = ||B||^2$

But I am not able to proceed further. Help, please.

After proving this, I will be proceeding like this

$||{A^2}^n||^2$ = ${||A^*A||^2}^n$ = ${||A||^2}^{n+1}$ ( Since $A$ is normal therefore $||A^*A|| = ||A||^2$)

Hence $||{A^2}^n|| = {||A||^2}^n$.

Hence ${||{A^2}^n||}^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ = $||A||$

Hence ${||{A^2}^n||}^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ $\rightarrow$ $||A||$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now I want to know why does $\lim_{n}{||A^n||}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ even exists (I know that $||A||$ is bounded but how does it guarantee the existence of this limit).

After this, I think I will be done.

Please clarify the two doubts in the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for some integer $n$ we have that $\|B^{2^{n-1}}\|=\|B\|^{2^{n-1}}$. $B^{2^{n-1}}$ is also self-adjoint (see the comment section), so,

$$\|(B^{2^{n-1}})^2\|=\|B^{2^{n-1}}\|^2$$
so
$$\|B^{2^n}\|=(\|B\|^{2^{n-1}})^2=\|B\|^{2^n}$$
and this is the inductive step. The other question you have is the proof of the classical Gelfand-Beurling formula of the spectral radius (a quick search online will yield many proofs and there are plenty posts here about it).

Comment: The fact that   $\|B^{2^{n-1}}\|=\|B\|^{2^{n-1}}$ does not imply that $B^{2^{n-1}}$ is self-adjoint, since every
normal matrix satisfies this property.  In fact any block matrix of the form $1\oplus B$, with $\|B\|\leq 1$, also
satisfies this property.

Comment: To my knowledge “then” means “$\Rightarrow$”, while “since” means “$\Leftarrow$”.  So it is very risky to confuse these two!